# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, compatibility, 16.04

I am planning to upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 as soon as a stable version is released. How can I **check easily** that whether all my current apps will be compatible and supported on the new LTS version instead of visiting each apps' website and finding out?

Comment: Why do you assume they will not work? Anyone gave you the impression they would not? Ubuntu tends to be as backwards compatible as possible from what I noticed in the past and 16.04 is an LTS, and those tend to be on the cautious side (ie. targeted more to stable than to new). Nonetheless: I agree with Charles Green though I would wait for a few months. The 14.04->16.04 upgrade path will arrive -later- than the 16.04 relasese. It will be the 16.04.2 release that lets you do that. At that time all features of 16.04 are known and used already.

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually I am concerned about Matlab (Linux version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install a virtual machine manager, such as VMPlayer or VirtualBox, load Ubuntu 16.04 into that, and  within the virtual machine test all of your applications.